# Singly Linked List Implementation using C# - RemoveLast Method

Tags: c#, singly-linked-list

I've implemented Singly linked list using C# . Can anyone please look into the following code and suggest where I'm wrong?

```
public int RemoveLast()
{
    if (Head != null)
    {
         var curNode = Head;

         while (curNode.Next != null)
         {
              curNode = curNode.Next;
         }

         var lastNodeValue = curNode.Value;

         curNode = null;
         Size--;
         return lastNodeValue;
     }

     return -1;
}
```

This function does not remove the last node. I'm unable to figure out what's wrong. When while loop ends, we have the reference of node in curNode whose next is null. It means this is the last node. At the end, I'm setting this node to null. But when I use Display function. It displays the last node as well. This is not deleting the last node.

Here is my display function:

```
    public string Display()
    {
        if (Head == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var curNode = Head;
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        while (curNode.Next != null)
        {
            builder.Append($"{curNode.Value} ");
            curNode = curNode.Next;
        }

        builder.Append($"{curNode.Value} ");

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: You are just clearing your currNode. It doesn't delete anything from the list. Expected bahavior. You'd have to clear the `Next` property of your *second last* Node to delete the last node.

Comment: You're not changing a `.Next` property to null. You're just changing a local reference to null.

Comment: My guess is that curNode is a local copy of the List Element. Not the actuall list Element.
Having curNode being a var makes it ambigious what type it is. You should propably repalce it with explicit typisation. Taht is exactly the kind of case where you should not use var.

Comment: try to change your while to check the `curNode.Next.Next == null` and set `curNode.Next = null`

Comment: @SebastianL what if size = 1 ? `currNode.Next.Next` will throw an NPE!

Comment: `curNode = curNode.Next;` and `curNode = null;` use exactly the same assignment. And yet you expected them to do vastly different things. Consider that carefully before continuing.

Comment: @Fildor: But local reference is pointing to the last node and I'm setting it to null. Why it doesn't work this way?

Comment: You have two pieces of paper. On both you write down your street address. Now you burn one of them. Will the writing vanish from the other?

Comment: But in context of C#, change in one object makes changes all of the objects pointing to the same memory location.
In my case, its not a deep copy but the shallow one..

Comment: @MuhammadQasim You're not changing the object, you're changing the reference to it.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim What you describe in my example would be you moving to a different location and you update the address on both pieces of paper. You have to be careful what exactly you are changing. The reference or the referenced object.

Comment: ahhh I've got it now. Thanks James for the explanation. Im simply changing the reference. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[x] -> [x] -> [x] -> null
               ^
               curNode (becomes null)
           ^
           this reference still exists
```

When doing `curNode = null` you do not change any reference in the list. `curNode` variable is changed only, it is pointing to the last element before operation and becomes *null* afterwards.

Try always keep reference to the node before last:

```
public int RemoveLast()
{
    if (Head != null)
    {
        var curNode = Head;
        // Corner case when there is only one node in the list
        if (Head.Next == null)
        {
            Head = null;
            Size--;
            return curNode.value;
        }

        var beforeLastNode = curNode;
        curNode = curNode.Next;
        while (curNode.Next != null)
        {
            beforeLastNode = curNode;
            curNode = curNode.Next;
        }

        var lastNodeValue = curNode.Value;

        beforeLastNode.Next = null;
        Size--;
        return lastNodeValue;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the last-but-one node, and change its `Next` to null:

```
public int RemoveLast()
{
    if (Head != null)
    {
        var curNode = Head;

        while (curNode.Next?.Next != null)
        {
            curNode = curNode.Next;
        }

        var lastNodeValue = curNode.Next?.Value ?? -1;
        curNode.Next = null;
        Size--;
        return lastNodeValue;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Note that if you also want `Head` to be set to null if its the only node, then you can do that like so:

```
public int RemoveLast()
{
    if (Head != null)
    {
        var curNode = Head;

        while (curNode.Next?.Next != null)
        {
            curNode = curNode.Next;
        }

        int lastNodeValue;

        if (Head.Next == null)
        {
            lastNodeValue = Head.Value;
            Head = null;
        }
        else
        {
            lastNodeValue = curNode.Next?.Value ?? -1;
        }
        curNode.Next = null;
        Size--;
        return lastNodeValue;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I have to say though, this `Head` property looks a bit dubious - it should perhaps belong to a different class.

Comment: In case of size=1 , Head Node will not be removed, right?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, this issue here is this strange `Head` property. We can't really deal with that because we don't know what it is. So `Head` won't be altered. But I'll add an example saying what to do if it's needed.

Comment: After edit: Better but still not removing Head. I suspect it is a referecne in the list to the first Node, but you are right, OP should let us know. I'd add a check after the while: `if( curNode == Head) Head = null;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the curNode.Next value null on the previous node.
'curNode' is a local variable, setting it null doesn't do anything except maybe extend its GC life.

```
public int RemoveLast()
{
    if (Head != null)
    {
         var curNode = Head;
         var previousNode = null;

         while (curNode.Next != null)
         {
              previousNode = curNode;
              curNode = curNode.Next;
         }

         var lastNodeValue = curNode.Value;

         if (previousNode == null)
             Head = null;
         else
             previousNode.Next = null;
         Size--;
         return lastNodeValue;
     }

     return -1;
}
```

Comment: Here also: What if size == 1?

Answer (score 0):

okay guys, after your help, I've rewritten this method that meets all the requirements and set to HeadNode null if there is only one node in linked list. So here we go:

```
    public int RemoveLast()
    {
        if (HeadNode != null)
        {
            var currNode = HeadNode;
            var prevNode = HeadNode;

            if (HeadNode.Next == null)
            {
                HeadNode = null;
                Size--;
                return currNode.Value;
            }

            while (currNode.Next != null)
            {
                prevNode = currNode;
                currNode = currNode.Next;
            }

            prevNode.Next = null;
            Size--;
            return currNode.Value;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Thank you everyone who contributed in this thread. Happy Coding :)